# Cancel All Subscriptions in Google Play

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

We currently try to cancel all subscriptions of an app in Google Play. We already contacted the Google Play support, but they told us that there are only two ways to do this:

- Manually for every subscriptions in the UI
- Using the Google Play API

For the API we need the purchase token of each subscription. I couldn't find a way to get all purchase tokens. The only way I found to get a purchase token is by manually requesting it through the UI.

We need to cancel a lot of subscriptions, so manually clicking around in the UI is no option for us. Is there a way to get all purchase tokens? Or is there a different way to cancel all subscriptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem, as of right now, it seems it's not possible to cancel all subscriptions using the Google Play API.

We have built a webhook for [real-time developer notifications](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/rtdn-reference). So for every subscription renewal that is triggered, we immediately revoke the subscription and refund the payment. This seems to work, but is far from great.

Edit: this worked and we cancelled all active subscriptions. It's still pretty annoying that there is no better way around it.